# How do we populate a group of <span> </span> with an array of words?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I populate a group of `<span> </span>` with an array of words with a loop?

If the array contains `[ "one", "two", "three" ]` and is called "wordarray"

Then I want to fill the spans so it looks like

```
<div id="mywords">
  <span> one </span>
  <span> two </span>
  <span> three </span>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery as well,

I tried this,

```
var index = 0;

wordarray.forEach(
 function(entry)
 {
     $("mywords").html(<span>entry</span>);
 }
 );
```

but I did not get the result I wanted.

Comment: use `.append()` instead of `.html()` and use quotes around span tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var wordarray = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
```

---

To create the spans:

```
$('#mywords').append(wordarray.map(function (word) {
    return $('<span>').text(word);
}));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0tuqfh8/)

---

If the spans already exist:

```
$('#mywords span').each(function(i, span) {
    $(span).text(wordarray[i]);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0tuqfh8/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```
wordarray.forEach(function(entry) {
    $("#mywords").append('<span>' + entry + '</span>');
});
```

If you can't delete the spans for any reason:

```
$('#mywords').find('span').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).html(wordarray[i]);
});
```

- [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Better hope one of the words isn't `"<script>alert();</script>"`.

Comment: I think the words are going to be "one", "two", and "three".

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this ([Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/71sgckaa/)):

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
$('#mywords').html('<span>' + arr.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
```

This is [faster](http://jsperf.com/array-join-and-loop) than `forEach` loop.

**Update**: For already available empty spans ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/71sgckaa/2/)):

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
$('#mywords > span').each(function(i, el){
    $(el).html(arr[i]);
});
```

Comment: Down Voter, please explain the reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the level of kludge here is somewhat painful.

Comment: Well but it's even without a loop.

Comment: There are so many ways but this is just one approach with looping.

Comment: If `map` and `forEach` count as loops, then `join` does too.

Comment: Check [this test](http://jsperf.com/array-join-and-loop), `join` is faster than `forEach`.

Comment: Sometimes you optimize for performance... more often for readability and security.

Comment: Lol... Is there a chance for that ? I don't think so because page is your and you know what is safe for you.

Comment: Or maybe you work on a team and five years later someone else will make a change elsewhere in the application that affects the values in this array and that person won't be aware of the assumptions you've made about the character set.

Comment: I'm not going to think about that right now but anything is possible. Are we talking about best practice or just answered a little newbie question. My concern is that, there are so many ways to do that, use one or another bur this is nothing so much serious, I'm leaving it here. My answer is not wrong either, anyways. All the best :-)